# No Blank Cordova Project in VS 2015 CTP 6 for visual-studio-cordova

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

After installing the latest CTP 6 of Visual Studio 2015, I don't have the option to create a new Apache Cordova Multi Device project from the templates. Do I need to install something else? I believe I have all the dependencies checked during installation.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

This issue will occur if you have installed VS to your non-system drive.

In that case you can workaround it by copying and merging the contents of the "~\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Ide\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\WebClient"
 folder from the standard install location on the system drive to your custom location, and then running "devenv /setup" from an elevated VS developer command prompt.  This bug will be fixed in the next public release.

The issue will also occur if you have upgraded to CTP6 directly from CTP5, without first uninstalling CTP5.

In that case the workaround is:
1. Go to Control Panel, choose Repair on Tools for Apache Cordova MSI. 
[image: Repair MSI]

2. Verify that C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\JavaScript\Apache Cordova Apps\1033\blankCordovaJS is populated.
3. From elevated developer command prompts run devenv /setup
   [image: Command prompt]

Open VS and your Cordova project template is back.

Comment: Ellen, sorry, that didn't help. It is installed to the system-drive. Here's the directory of the solution, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\WebClient and it exists.

Comment: David, to help diagnose this issue, please email vscordovatools@microsoft.com with the javascript project system install log. You can find it in the %temp% folder with the name ending with ...JavaScript_ProjectSystem.msi.log  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ellen :) after struggling with this for a while, your command prompt method worked for me!

Comment: This worked for me. I had installed visual studio on drive u. Merging the two folders and running devenv /setup worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when updating from VS Preview to CTP 5 and again from CTP 5 to CTP 6. To fix the problem I ran the "Modify" option to check Cordova Tools were actually selected (it was) and then the "Repair" option from the VisualStudio CTP setup. Now it workes like a charm.

To open previously created projects I also had to change the import nodes in the *.jsproj file from

```
$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\...
```

to

```
$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets
```

Comment: After a repair, VS failed to launch without crashing instantly. Trying an uninstall and reinstall now.